# How to get footer where I want it

Tags: css, footer

I have a page with the following structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Dashboard</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/coachmaster.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dashboard.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="outer">
  <div id="wrap1">
    <img id="logo" src="/images/dashboard.png" />
    <div id="status">Status</div>
    <div id="menu">Menu</div>
  </div>
  <div id="grip1" ></div>
  <div id="wrap2">
    <div id="content">
      <table class="title"><tr><td>Ian's Dashboard</td></tr></table>
      <div class="fields">This is the screen content
      </div>
      <table class="listhead"><tr>.. row of command buttons... </tr></table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The key CSS fragment are:

```
div.fields {
  position: absolute;
  top: 32px;  bottom: 36px;
  width: 99.8%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border-right:1px solid #d3d1d1;
  border-left:1px solid #d3d1d1;
}
table.listhead {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

This means that the .listhead table is always at the bottom of the screen, and when the div.fields gets too big for the space available, a vertical scroll bar appears.

The customer wants the table.listhead moved up to butt on to the div.fields so any spare space appears below it.

I have tried everything I can think of to achieve this, and failed. I wondered about wrapping div.fields with table.listhead, but I could not get anything to work.

Is it even possible?

Thanks. Ian

Comment: If you try making a JSFiddle with your code, I'm sure someone can help you out faster.  Cheers.

Comment: I've tried to make a jsFiddle of the problem. No js and images missing - see http://jsfiddle.net/rCFng/1/  - the footer should show an image that reads "edit".

Answer (score 0):

a little easier to understand now, thanks! :)

I would try playing around with position, I could move the bottom table up by doing:

```
table.listhead {
  position:relative;
  top: 285px;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, but it won't help. The exact value needed for the 286 depends upon the current screen depth and therefore requires javascript. I don't want to use JS if I can help it.